# Add Upsell Product On Checkout Cart Page -Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, layout, magento2.2.2

How to we can add upsell products on checkout cart page as crossell products in Magento 2.3.5 ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can show Upsell products on checkout page by add below code to **`checkout_index_index.xml`**

Try this code :-

> **`app/design/frontend/YourVendorName/YourTheme/Magento_Checkout`**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="checkout" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Upsell" name="checkout.cart.upsell" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/items.phtml" after="-">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">upsell</argument>
                </arguments>
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\Container" name="upsell.product.addto" as="addto">
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\AddTo\Compare"
                           name="upsell.product.addto.compare" as="compare"
                           template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/addto/compare.phtml"/></block>
            </referenceBlock>
        </body>
    </page>
```

After change you run command :-

```
php bin/magento c:c
php bin/magento c:f
```

**`THANKS.`**